# JavaFx, обновление сцены

Tags: javafx

Делаю программу которая генерирует бинарное дерево добавляя кнопки на панель и соединяя их линией. При добавлении нового элемента он просто появляется в координатах `(0,0)` и встает в нужное место только если поменять размер окна(конечно я пробовал увеличить размер на один пиксель, но это ужасный костыль).
Я не смог найти метода перерисовки `repaint(), revalidate()` как в `Swing`.
Как можно обновить расположение компонента?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте у компонента задать новые параметры, а потом вызвать у `Pane` к которой он принадлежит метод `requestLayout()`

Это должно выглядеть, примерно, так

```
public class Solution extends Application {
  private static final Pane root = new Pane();
  private static final Circle circle = new Circle(20, 20, 20);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("repaint");
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + 50);
                circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + 50);
                circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() * 1.1);
                root.requestLayout();
            });
        }
    }, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));

    launch(args);
 }

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("simple example");

    root.getChildren().add(circle);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}}
```